# Pass the url of the current domain in axios VueJS

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to pass the url of the domain where I am to pass it in axios. Here is my current hard url:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'cart',
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {
            cart: '',
            timer: '',
            baseUrl: 'http://prestashop_1_6.local/modules/analyticsvuejs/php/cart.php',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCarts() {
            axios
                .get(this.baseUrl, {
                    params: {
                        action: 'cart'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                        this.cart = response.data;
                        console.log(this.cart);
                    }, (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                )
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.getCarts();
        this.timer = setInterval(this.getCarts, 5000)
    },
}
```

and I'm trying to create a variable to dynamically pass it to all my components

I am looking to replace 'http: //prestashop_1_6.local/' with a dynamic variable.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `http://prestashop_1_6.local` the domain of the site that you’re currently browsing? If so, you can just omit that part entirely and just use the rest as the base url. It’s preferred anyways, when the domain is the same. It makes your code transfer from your development environment to production without modification.

Comment: Yes I have to call this URL obligatorily even if I am on this url because it calls a module in particular

Comment: So, one thing I would suggest is making your baseUrl simply be `'/modules/analyticsvuejs/php/cart.php'`. The browser will use the same protocol/domain that you're currently at (`http://prestashop_1_6.local`), but now if you make this request from different domains, it automatically just works. No need to change the `baseUrl` when you deploy to production or anything. Now, if you need that `/modules/analyticsvuejs/php/cart.php` part used in multiple Vue files, then consider doing like @AfikDeri said and put that into a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a separate file with a const containing this base url.

2) export this const

3) use it wherever you want

```
// consts.js

export const BASE_URL = 'http://prestashop_1_6.local';


// Any file that consume it.
import {BASE_URL} from './consts';

data() {
  return {
    url: `${BASE_URL}/something/something-else`
  };
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically recover the value to put it in the constant ? export const BASE_URL = my_variable_here;